# Jenkins Warnings Plugin - Content is not allowed in prolog error

Tags: jenkins, jslint, csslint

Today, I setup Warnings Plugin, and use CssLint and JSLint but after build I get error message to the all file:

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

This is my settings:
[image]

**Which cause this error and how to fix?** I probably set Default Encoding, but that didn't help.